# Sorting DataFrame and getting a value of column from it

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following dataframe:

```
newItem = pd.DataFrame({'c1': range(10), 'c2': (1,90,100,50,30,10,50,30,90,1000)})
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

I want to sort the columns by descending order, and extract the i'th row to a new pandas series.

So my function looks like this:

```
def getLargestRow(dataFrame, indexAfterSort):
    numRows, numCols = dataFrame.shape
    seriesToReturn = pd.Series()
    dataFrame= dataFrame.sort_values(by=list(df.columns), ascending = False)
```

My problem is that I can't get to concatenate dataFrame's row number indexAfterSort.
I've tried to use:

```
seriesToReturn = seriesToReturn.add(df.iloc[indexAfterSort])
```

But confusingly I got NaN values, instead of the row values.
The dataframe after sort:
[image]

The output I receive (no matter what's the input for row index):
[image]

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thank you, I forgot to add it. Instead of receiving the NaN values, I want to receive the row sitting in index indexAfterSort that the function receives.

Comment: Please post the expected output. The exact one that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use built-in pandas functions for simple operations like sorting. Function [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) is a good option here. This sorts the rows of the dataframe by `c1` column:

```py
seriesToReturn = newItem.sort_values('c1', ascending=False)
```

This returns a dataframe with both `c1` and `c2` columns, to get series of `c2` column, just use `seriesToReturn = seriesToReturn['c2']`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I would like the function to be generic, no matter how many columns it has. So I would like not to mention specific column names in the function.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you want to achieve? In the example you gave, it seems it's just sorted by the `c1` column. Do you want to sort by all the columns?